# How to write an if else statement in Aura

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-if

I tried to write out the aura if statement but I am getting stuck if someone can explain it to me in detail. thank you

```
 <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(v.Tl.time, v.Tl.End_Date_Time1__c)}">
                 
         </aura:if>
```

Comment: Why are you removing detail and code from your questions? To make your participation here successful and rewarding, it helps to learn our format. Please take a moment to explore our [tour] and read [ask], then make an [edit] to _add_ all the information about your problem to this post.

Answer (score 6):

You "[aura:set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_set_intro.htm)" the else attribute:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(v.TelevisitRecord.Date_and_Time_of_Contact__c, v.TelevisitRecord.End_Date_Time1__c)}">
  Content when true
  <aura:set attribute="else">
    Content when false
  </aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: the ares that say content when true and false, do there need t be code added in there?

Comment: @mia Set "Content when true" to whatever you would like to display when the condition is true, and "Content when false" to whatever you want to show when the condition is false.

Comment: Yeah that's weird.